# get text from pdf and word with flutter dart

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub

I want get all text from pdf or word file from user and I want do that from flutter application not from apis or backend.
is there any library in dart or flutter do that?

Answer (score 3):

-We can extract the text from PDF file using different packages like [syncfusion_flutter_pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf) (recommended) and [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf).

-But I could not find any Package to extract text from a Word file.

-**We can extract the text from a Word file by converting the Word file into a txt file using an API, then can extract the text from that txt file.**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this with a flutter plugin, however you can do this natively using PDFBox library for android and call the methods from your native thread. If you haven't done this yet, if you see this and still need this functionality but dont know how to implement natively, leave a comment and ill publish a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I found one [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_text) maybe it's useful for you.